# $\sum_{i=1}^x\sum_{j=1}^xf(i\cdot j)$ Double Summing a (Not Completely) Multiplicative Function

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, functions, summation, algorithms

Let $f(n)$ be a multiplicative function that is **not** completely multiplicative, i.e $f(m)\cdot f(n)= f(m\cdot n)$ only if $gcd(m,n)=1$. Let $S(x)$ be the double sum over $f$, that is:

$$S(x)=\sum_{i=1}^x\sum_{j=1}^xf(i\cdot j)$$

It is not difficult to see that if $f(n)$ were completely multiplicative, then $S(x)$ could be simplified:

$$S(x)=\sum_{i=1}^x\sum_{j=1}^xf(i\cdot j)= \sum_{i=1}^xf(i)\sum_{j=1}^xf(j)= \biggl(\sum_{k=1}^xf(k)\biggr)^2$$

But since $f(n)$ is not completely multiplicative, this simplification is not completely true, and it fails every time $gcd(i,j)\neq1$. Hence, $S(x)$ can be written this way provided we add some additional error term, let's call it $E$:

$$S(x)=\sum_{i=1}^x\sum_{j=1}^xf(i\cdot j)= \biggl(\sum_{k=1}^xf(k)\biggr)^2+E$$

$E$ is either negative or positive, I'm not sure. Obviously, $E$ is comprised of all the small errors generated by the initial sum term, when $gcd(i,j)\neq1$. I am mainly interested in the cases where $f(n)$ takes the form of:

1. Euler totient function: $$S_{\varphi}(x)=\sum_{i=1}^x\sum_{j=1}^x\varphi(i\cdot j)$$
2. Sum of divisors function: $$S_{\sigma_1}(x)=\sum_{i=1}^x\sum_{j=1}^x\sigma_1(i\cdot j)$$
3. Moebius function: $$S_{\mu}(x)=\sum_{i=1}^x\sum_{j=1}^x\mu(i\cdot j)$$

My question is, what is this error term $E$ exactly? how can I calculate it? How can I properly sum all those small errors to get a correct evaluation of $S(x)$? For clarification, I am concerned with evaluating $S(x)$, but I think I must evaluate $E$ first in order to do it. I am taking this approach because I can compute $\biggl(\sum_{k=1}^xf(k)\biggr)^2$ very efficiently, and so, finding the error term $E$ will solve my question.

Comment: I don't think you should be thinking of it as an error term. I feel like $S(x)$ has nothing to do with $(\sum_{k=1}^x f(k))^2$ for a general multiplicative function. For the three examples you gave, you're just asking someone to compute two quantities separately and find their difference $S(x)-(\sum_{k=1}^x f(k))^2$. That's my guess at least

Comment: I want to evaluate $S(x)$. Are you implying I can directly calculate $S(x)$ without computing $E$ first? If so, then how? @mathworker21

Comment: I was trying to say that evaluating $S(x)$ seems as hard as evaluating $E$, or even easier. I'm objecting to the last statement in your post.

Comment: Well, then do you have any way of evaluating $S(x)$ directly? Because I have been at it for quite a while, and this is the best I've come up with, because I can compute $(\sum_{k=1}^x f(k))^2$ rather efficiently - to the point I can say if $f(n)$ were completely multiplicative I would have no trouble at all. @mathworker21

Comment: i doubt you can evaluate it for an arbitrary multiplicative function like you did for completely multiplicative functions (since you have many more choices in defining a multiplicative function), so you have to make arguments based on the given example. For instance, $\mu(i \cdot j) = 0$ if $\gcd(i,j) > 1$, so $S_\mu(x) = \sum_{i=1}^x \sum_{\gcd(j,i) = 1, j \le x} \mu(i \cdot j)$ and $\mu(i\cdot j) = \mu(i)\mu(j)$ if $\gcd(i,j) = 1$. Idk, try to go from here

Comment: Can you explain what you did and how? What are all the notations and how they're derived @reuns

Comment: $$\sum_{i \le x, j \le x} f(ij)= \sum_{i j \le x} f(ij)+\sum_{i \le x, x/i < j \le x} f(ij) = \sum_{n \le x} f(n)\sum_{i | n}1  +\sum_{x < n\le x^2} f(n) \sum_{i | n, n/x \le i \le x} 1\\ = \sum_{n \le x^2} f(n) \tau(n)-2\sum_{n\le x^2} f(n) \sum_{i | n,i > x} 1$$


 Depending on the growth of $f$ it is the first or second term which dominates (with $\mu(n)$ both will be chaotic, better try with non-negative $f$)

Comment: This question now has a copy at Mathoverflow: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/332923/sum-i-1x-sum-j-1xfi-cdot-j-double-summing-a-not-completely-multipli